# multiple file upload to a list

Tags: custom-list, file-upload

My customer asked a component list for event announcements, and after event done they would like to upload event photos, videos or related files.

I told them to use attachment but they have like 500+ photos and 10+ videos and attachment only accept one file at a time.

They were even okay if we can simple make a link to local files, but SharePoint doesn't accept such links I guess.(`<a href="file:///\\myserver\doc\">Link</a>`)

Now I am thinking to make a document library which gets a parameter from query for event Item Id, and add a link in event announcements list newform(without editing newform.aspx) such a burden, any one done things like this, please guide me with your best approach.

thanks

Comment: How about working with a fileshare - you could index it via the search and then use a searchcenter to give users options the search for the files wanted (mostly via the path since metadata are quite complicated to implement in this scenario)

Comment: Or create a second list where the client can upload his files and add a lookup-field where he can reference the event. since the data is now associated you could use the search (or even the jsom wrapper for list access) to show the files for the event.

Comment: Are you okay with creating a link that opens an Explorer window in the user's PC? Then the user can just drag and drop.

Comment: Mx. yesterday they have to select the event from lookup for each file. we like to do something practical, like bulk drag-drop upload.